# I dont understand how to implement the Deleting Requests in request dialog

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I have read the document [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting)
but I don't understand how should I implement it right.
In my facebook app I use `apprequests` from JS api like this:

```
function newInvite() {
   var msg = document.getElementById('msg_look_id').value;

   var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: msg,
      title: "Select friends to send your gift",
   },

   function (response) {
      alert("IDS : " + response.request_ids);
   });
   //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
}
```

then the user see the request in its app request icon (with the red numbers )
the user click it , but then how do I implement the delete request ?

Answer (score 1):

When the user arrives at your app’s canvas page following a request, there is a parameter called `request_ids` passed to your app.

Since Facebook calls apps in the iframe using the HTTP method POST, I guess this is also a POST parameter (although it is not explicitly mentioned in the docs). That means you have no access to it using pure client-side JavaScript; you have to use a server-side script to get the content of this parameter.